# Defining params in React Router v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Since the update to React Router v6 the way to render children with params has changed. Previously in v5 you could define expected params in the URL to render a child based on an expected param, but now you can't. Currently updating from v5 to v6 and it's causing issues with routing currently.

I have looked through a few locations in the new documentation, but can't seem to find what I am looking for:

- [API reference](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api)
- [Main Concepts](https://reactrouterdotcom.fly.dev/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#review)

From the documentation:

```
<Route path="parent" element={<Parent />}>
  <Route path=":child" element={<Child />} />
</Route>
```

What I am trying to do:

```
<Route path="parent/:child" element={<Parent />}>
  <Route path="parent/child1" element={<Child1 />} />
  <Route path="parent/child2" element={<Child2 />} />
</Route>
```

In v5 you could do something where you define the params you expect:

```
path="parent/:child(child1|child2)"
```

Is there any way to do this in v6 now? The documents are pretty sparse and not very descriptive. Anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

The `Route` components in RRDv6 don't take REGEX paths anymore. You can read more in depth about that in [What Happened to Rexexp Routes Path?](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/faq#what-happened-to-regexp-routes-paths)

From what I can tell you weren't using the params as variables to access in the routed components, but more for condensed route definitions. In RRDv6 you explicitly render "child1"|"child2" nested route components.

```
<Route path="parent" element={<Parent />}>
  <Route path="child1" element={<Child1 />} /> // "../parent/child1"
  <Route path="child2" element={<Child2 />} /> // "../parent/child2"
</Route>
```

### Update

It seems you do want to use the `child` route param to help decide which component to render. For this abstract the `params` processing into the parent component that conditionally renders the child components.

Example:

```
const Parent = () => {
  const { child } = useParams();

  switch (child) {
    case "child1":
      return <Child1 />;

    case "child2":
      return <Child2 />;

    default:
      return null;
  }
};
```

...

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="parent/:child" element={<Parent />} />
</Routes>
```

[image: Edit defining-params-in-react-router-v6]

Comment: The problem with this is the use of `useParams` is now gone. Where the application would use the param passed in that help manage state and refresh of the page to keep people at current the URL.

Comment: @T.Evans The docs I linked explain how to do this in v6. Instead of relying on a route param you can simply pass in a prop to the the component, i.e. `<Route path="child1" element={<Child1 propICareAbout={someValue} />} />`. I'll see if I can stand a codesandbox up quickly and see if I can get any route params working like you are looking for, otherwise I think the above solution based on official recommendations is correct.

Comment: @T.Evans Are you trying to render one of `Child1` or `Child2` component based on the `child` route param value?

Comment: Correct, based on the param value I want to render certain components